# how to get user input in a batch file and use that value in our code in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I have created a bat file named test.bat as below :

```
sqlcmd -v item="%item%" -v cost=%cost% -i test.sql sqlcmd -S "172.16.253.72,17001" -U user -P pdw -d Master -I C:\Maintenance\test_blocking_backup\test.sql -o C:\Maintenance\test_blocking_backup\output.txt
```

so when i will run this file it should prompt me for the value of item and cost. but then how can i fetch the value entered by the user in a variable

Answer (score 0):

Using **.Bat file** with input Parameters

1) With Prompt:

add before your sqlcmd line

```
echo off
set /p item=Enter item: 
set /p cost=Enter cost:
```

2) without Prompt :

add before your sqlcmd line

```
set item=%1
set cost=%2
```

Then call your bat file like this

**test.bat itemvalue,costvalue**

where itemvalue and costvalue are the parameters values to pass to the .bat file